# Given that $f(\cdot)$ is a convex function of $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n_+$, is Problem $\mathbf{P}$ convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Given that $f(\cdot)$ is a convex function of $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n_+$, is Problem $\mathbf{P}$ convex?
$$(\mathbf{P})\min_{x_1,\cdots,x_n}f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\\
s.t. \quad\max\{1-x_1,\cdots,1-x_n\}\ge 0$$

Comment: No. The $\max$ function is convex, so the inequality "goes the wrong way"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any idea to handle this kind problem?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: Simplest way is probably solving $n$ instances of $\min f(x)$, where you use the constraint $1-x_i \geq 0$ in instance $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposed problem is not convex, since the inequality "goes the wrong way".

One way to model/solve such a problem is to formulate the $\max$ function using binary variables. As an example, suppose we want to enforce the constraint

$$ \max\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\geqslant0. $$

This approach requires us to know a positive constant (typically called $M$) such that $-M$ is a lower bound on the values of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ that we care about.

**Note**: Arbitrarily choosing some huge $M$ value can have bad computational side effects--it's best to think about the problem you're solving and come up with the best lower bounds possible.

Suppose that we have $M>0$ such that $-M\leqslant{x_i}$ is a valid lower bound for $i=1,2,3$ (in practice we could choose three constants $M_i$ for each $x_i$, but I'm keeping things simple).

Then introduce a binary variable $z_i\in\{0,1\}$ for each $i=1,2,3$, and add the constraints

$$
x_i+Mz_i\geqslant0\text{ for }i=1,2,3
$$
and
$$
z_1+z_2+z_3\leqslant2.
$$
The constraint $z_1+z_2+z_3\leqslant2$ means that there will be at least one $z_i=0$. For this $i$, the first constraint becomes $x_i\geqslant0$. Hence there exists an $i$ such that $x_i\geqslant0\Rightarrow\max\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\geqslant0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I shall think about it.

Comment: These big-$M$ constraints (as they're called) are pretty standard in the world of operations research, mixed-integer programming, etc. They definitely take a little thought and getting used to.

Comment: You mentioned in the above that CVX can be used here. I notice that the transformed problem by introducing binary variables is a discrete problem, so are you sure that CVX can solve the problem?

Comment: The [CVXPY docs](http://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#mixed-integer-programs) indicate that you can (as long as you pair with a solver that can handle integer variables)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: CVX can handle this, using the big M formulation, providing that you have the CVX professional (including academic) version , not the free version, and have an integer-capable solver installed, and providing that f(x() is representable in CVX - not all convex functions are. Nor will CVXPY accept all convex functions.

Comment: What is your convex function, f(x)?  BTW, I'd have enough to buy several cups of Starbucks coffee if I got a dime for every time someone on the CVX forum erroneously claimed their function or optimization problem is convex.